# PayPal API set return URL

Tags: java, api, paypal

With the oldest PayPal API, setting the return URL when a checkout is accomplishment, or when checkout is eliminated is easy, as described here:

```
Payment payment = new Payment();
RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
redirectUrls.setCancelUrl(cancelUrl);
redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(successUrl);
payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);
```

How can I accomplished this goal with new PayPal API?
I have already setting an url return (google.com for testing) in my sandbox account but it seems not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which new API? There are several. Are you using the Checkout-Java-SDK? The best integrations do not use a redirect, and hence do not need a return URL.

Instead, implement two routes on your server that return JSON data -- one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).

The approval flow to pair those two routes with is: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This flow does not redirect away, hence there is no need or use for a return URL and if specified it will be ignored.

> I have already setting an url return (google.com for testing) in my sandbox account but it seems not work.

That is for non-API integrations that use a link or HTML form post. There is no API integration that pays any attention to that profile setting.

Comment: I'm working with java + Spring for backend and I can't understand how implement this new mechanism of 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order'. When I call "Create Order" on my server I obtain a HttpResponse that contains transition id and approved order link as: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=1CG34074PA219512D
but when I do the checkout I'm stuck in "We are redirect you on EXAMPLE INC".

CreateOrder from here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/

Comment: I found new ApplicationContext()
        .returnUrl("http://localhost:5001/pay/success")
        .cancelUrl("http://localhost:5001/pay/cancel"); ..problem solved!

Comment: Yes, that works. But it is best to use https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server for the approval, then no redirect away from your site is needed

Comment: Your suggest is better, thank you! Approved!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post now but with REST API, there is a way to return these URLs. If you go to https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/ and click the application_context object link, you would be able to see the other details you can add to pass into your payload -- eg. brand_name, return_url, cancel_url etc. I do not think that Paypal has provided now an SDK but would love to know if there is. Right now, only the REST endpoints and payloads are available on their developer page.

[image]